# When can criminals be witnessed?

Tags: apb-reloaded

Under what circumstances can Enforcers witness Criminals?  I know about the handcuff icon, but it does not always appear.  Sometimes I see people mugging and ram-raiding, and I can only witness them once they've handed their loot in to their contact.